# Xamarin.Android handling listview scrolling

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new in Xamarin.Android and I want create custom animation like [Android Market (app details page)](https://armijnvink.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/spotify-scrolling-effect-2014/). My problem is handling scroll of listview for changing Top position of image and list.
I subscribe to listView.ViewTreeObserver.ScrollChanged event but when it fired - ScrollY property of listview equals 0. Here is my [question](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33360/scrolling-effect?new=1) in Xamarin Forum.
Help me please!

Comment: Try using listView.Scroll event.